# ¿Como convertir en formato json un objeto String java?

Tags: java, json, foreach, gson

Tengo que mostrar en un campo la respuesta del servicio con la siguiente estructura, pueden ser n preguntas, con su id y su respuesta

```html
{"idEncuesta": "09", "pregunta": "¿Cuantos años tienes?", "respuesta": "23", "idEncuesta": "10", "pregunta": "¿Trabajas?", "respuesta": "Si"}
```

tengo el siguiente código que consulta al servicio

```html
ResponseServicio respuesta = new ResponseServicio();
RespuestaSoap port = servicio.getEncuesta();
respuesta = port.consultaEncuesta();

String idPregunta = respuesta.getEncuesta().getPreguntas().get(0).getIdPregunta();
String prgunta = respuesta.getEncuesta().getPreguntas().get(0).getPregunta();
String respuesta = respuesta.getEncuesta().getPreguntas().get(0).getRespuesta();

String preguntas = idPregunta.concat(pregunta).concat(respuesta);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(preguntas);

resultado.put("ENCUESTA", json);
```

y lo que estoy haciendo solo muestra la primer pregunta ya que estoy colocando la posición 0 en mis variables, pero como le hago si quiero mostrar todas las preguntas que puedan venir, no solo la de la primer posicion??

Esta es la estructura de las clases que estoy llamando en mi objeto respuesta

```html
public class ResponseServicio{
  protected String codigo;
  protected Encuesta encuesta;

}

public class Encuesta{
  protected List<Preguntas> preguntas;


}

public class Preguntas{

   protected String idPregunta;
   protected String pregunta;
   protected String respuesta;
}
```

y mi resultado me lo muestra asi

```html
"09¿Cuantos años tienes?25"
```

como le hago para que me lo muestre como deseo, que me muestre todas las preguntas que puedan venir?

Comment: Veo que no estas usando Encuesta, y allí es donde debes meter la lista de preguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El JSON que estás tratando de armar está mal formado. Para guardar **n** preguntas en formato JSON podrías construir un JSON como éste:

```
{
    "preguntas": [{
            "idPregunta": "09",
            "pregunta": "¿Cuantos años tienes?",
            "respuesta": "23"
        },
        {
            "idPregunta": "10",
            "pregunta": "¿Trabajas?",
            "respuesta": "Si"
        }
    ]
}
```

`preguntas` sería el nodo raíz el cual es un array de preguntas y para extraerlas recorres el JSON extrayendo cada una.

Para armar el JSON a partir de un objeto de tipo `Encuesta` podrías crear un método dentro de la clase `Encuesta` que arme el JSON a partir de la lista de preguntas recorriendo una por una. Así:

```
public String buildJSON() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{\"preguntas\":[");
    for(int i = 0; i < preguntas.size(); i++) {
        sb.append((i > 0) ? ",{" : "{");
        sb.append("\"idPregunta\": \"" + preguntas.get(i).idPregunta + "\",");
        sb.append("\"pregunta\": \"" + preguntas.get(i).pregunta + "\",");
        sb.append("\"respuesta\": \"" + preguntas.get(i).respuesta + "\"");
        sb.append("}");
    }
    sb.append("]}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Ahora solo tienes que llamar al método usando el objeto encuesta así:

```
String json = encuesta.buildJSON();
System.out.println(json); //Muestra el JSON en pantalla.
```

Comment: me ayudo muchisimo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que la respuesta es un array con todas las preguntas y respuestas. Si es así entonces puedes recorrer la estructura y hacer lo que vienes haciendo solo que dentro de un ciclo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < respuesta.getEncuesta().getPreguntas().size(); i++){
   String idPregunta = respuesta.getEncuesta().getPreguntas().get(i).getIdPregunta();
   String prgunta = respuesta.getEncuesta().getPreguntas().get(i).getPregunta();
   String respuesta = respuesta.getEncuesta().getPreguntas().get(i).getRespuesta();
   ....Pones el resto de tu código dentro del for y ya lo tienes.
}
```

Comment: ya implemente esta parte, y al poner un System si visualizo las n preguntas en mi variable preguntas, pero en mi campo de respuesta del servicio solo visualizo la ultima pregunta que viene, no todas las que trae la lista